# The existence of a path of a length given

Tags: graph-theory

I got stuck on this problem from my graph theory class. The problem goes

> Let G a connected graph with n vertex,if there is a k positive integer such that
> $$ 2\leq{k}\leq{n-1} \text{ and } (xy\notin{E(G)} \implies{} deg(x)+deg(y)\geq{k})$$
> then there is a a path of length k in G.

Any hint?

Comment: Think about what happens when there is no path of length k in G. Then the longest path P in G has length at most k - 1. Can you reach a contradiction by examining P more closely?

Comment: @araomis I know that the endpoint of a path cannot be an edge but I can't see the contradiction with the other hypothesis, only that k must be greater than 4 because all the points of the path are the only neighbors of the endpoints.

Comment: Ok, so another hint is: The assumption that $G$ is connected is very important. What does it tell you about your path $P$? Also, I assume you have seen a proof of Ore's theorem in your lecture?

Comment: I haven't seen it yet, but I think with that I got it:). Thank you so much for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a fairly challenging exercise.

Are you familiar w the proof of Ore's Thm?

1. If, for any integer $k'$; $3 \le k'<n$ $=|V(G)|$, there is a *cycle* with $k'$ vertices in $G$, then that $G$ is ***connected*** implies that there is a *path* w $k'+1$ vertices. This is true for general graphs $G$. See if you can see why.
2. Let $k'$ be an integer less than $k$, such that a longest path $P$ in $G$ has $k'$ vertices. Write $P'=v_1v_2\ldots v_{k'}$, where $v_1$ and $v_{k'}$ are the endpoints of $P$. Then $v_1$ and $v_{k'}$ both have all neighbors in $P$ each, lest $P'$ could be extended. And furthermore, per 1., $v_1$ and $v_{k'}$ are not adjacent to each other. So furthermore, $d_G(v_1)+d_G(v_{k'})$ must be at least $k$.
3. But then by the proof of Ore's Thm [see e.g., Wikipedia] 2. implies that there is a cycle on $v_1,\ldots, v_{k'}$  $= V(P)$ that contains all $k'$ vertices after all. So conclude using 1. that there is indeed a path w $k'+1$ vertices.

The condition that $G$ is connected is necessary; otherwise $G$ could be a collection of vertex-disjoint cliques with somewhere between $k/2+1$ and $k-1$ vertices each.

Comment: No, I haven't seen it so far in my lecture. But thank you so much for writing it so clear:)